# setting up Strapi on AWS - the docs don't seem to show everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, strapi

I am trying to setup Strapi on AWS and am have been following the Strapi documentation [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/amazon-aws.html). But when I get to starting the EC2 instance, I have run into a few errors that were not addressed in in the docs. App keys, jwt secrets, and other env config variables. Has anyone else tried this and run into similar issues? And how did you get around things? I have been running `pm2 log` in my EC2 instance to get the errors.

I would post my config and everything but I have followed the strapi docs to the letter, and have run through every single step a dozen times now, and I don't want to basically copy and paste the docs in here again. My last step is to get Strapi to run on the EC2 instance, but I keep running into errors like this

```
error: Missing jwtSecret. Please, set configuration variable "jwtSecret" for the users-permissions plugin in config/plugins.js (ex: you can generate one using Node with `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')`).
```

which don't seem to be addressed in the docs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to expose the `JWT_SECRET` (and `ADMIN_JWT_SECRET`) environment variable. You can do it by adding (you can add a line like this: `JWT_SECRET=A_RANDOM_STRING_HERE`) it to the `.env` file located at the root of your Strapi project.

You can find more details here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#jwt-configuration

Comment: I'm still a little lost on where this all goes. I've worked with JWTs before, but perhaps I'm still a little confused on how they are implemented in this context. So, I have a completely random string set in my env. And a JWT is built based off that string? And am I writing the code to generate the JWT? I've added a random string to my EC2 ecosystem config file, but am getting that I am missing the apiToken.salt now, I assume because I haven't generated anything with the JWT secret.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate jwt

```
node -e "console.log(require('crypto').randomBytes(256).toString('base64'));"
```